# Rewrite Mage/Checkout/Block/Total/Default.php in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, overriding, block

I want to override Mage/Checkout/Block/Total/Default.php in order to make my own changes in checkout/total/default.phtml in Magento 1.7.0.2 but it's not working.

It's not my first time that I override a class in Magento, it always worked but not this time! There must be something different that is not similar to other Block modifications.

Here is what I did and it didn't work:

1. In [name_space]/Block/Default.php, I wrote:

   ```
   <?php
   class [name_space]_Block_Default extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Total_Default
   {
       protected $_template = '[name_space]/total/default.phtml';
   ...
   ```
2. In [name_space]/etc/config.xml, I added:

   ```
   <blocks>
       <checkout>
           <rewrite>
               <total_default>[name_space]_Block_Default</total_default>
           </rewrite>
       </checkout>
   </blocks>
   ```
3. I put default.phtml in [name_space]/total directory and changed it.

The result: I don't see my modifications, it's still pointing to Mage_Checkout_Block_Total_Default

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move that file to: `app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Total/Default.php` and you will not need to setup an XML for a rewrite.